# Visual Studio Sourcesafe 6.0 *.js filetype change default editor

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-sourcesafe

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Sourcesafe 6.0.
When edit `*.js(JavaScript)` File Type, the default text editor is `notepad.exe`, but I want to use another text editor.

How to change `*.js` File Type default text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can use notepad to view JavaScript source code. To change it, follow these steps:

1. Quit Internet Explorer (if it is running).
2. Double-click My Computer.
3. On the View menu, click Options (or Folder Options).
4. Click the File Types tab. In the Registered File Types box, find JavaScript, click it, and then click Edit. Then select your editor.

   Note: If it is not works, you may need to type a space and %1 at the end of the command. For example, if you want to use Notepad to be your default HTML editor, type the following command: `c:\windows\notepad.exe "%1"`
5. OK, click Close, and then click Close again.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163606/en-us

Does it really work? I don't know. But try it, please.

Comment: I find solution!! ss.ini file ".js (Win) = notepad.exe" delete ss.ini file location vss program installed (in my case : network drive )

Answer (score 0):

this can be easily done via Tools->Options menu in Visual SourceSafe Explorer. [How to: Change the Default Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8y215wa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)